# Java use jsoup to get data from html

Tags: jsoup

I use jsoup to get a document from a link

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element price = doc.select("td#flc_close").first();
```

The result is

```
<td id="flc_close" nowrap align="right" class="td_buy"><span class="priceup2">7.70</span></td>
```

How can I get 7.7 above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? You should edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `price.text()` and this will select 7.70 in this case.
If it is possible that the element contains text outside of the span and you only want to select what is inside the span, then:

`price.select("span").text()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup selector with matches. It gives the exact result you needed

```
String price=doc.select("span.priceup2:matches(\d+.\d+)").text();
```

Thanks